# Discord.js v12 | Delete invites from server

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I would my bot to delete invites created on my server with a command. I know I can take all invites with `message.guild.fetchInvites().then()`, but how do I make my lambda to delete all invites? Thank you in advance and excuse me If it is a dumb question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started off well, but here is how to loop through them all and delete them one by one:

```js
message.guild.invites.fetch().then(invites => {
  invites.each(i => i.delete())
})
```

<sup>Warning: If there are a lot of invites, you may get ratelimited. You can add a "sleep" function to fix this</sup>

Comment: It works! But I believe this is discord.js v13 so I had to tweak it but it still worked fine! `message.guild.fetchInvites().then(invites => { invites.each(i => i.delete()); });`